# Reproject VectorSource (or VectorLayer) in OpenLayers 7?

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, geojson, vector-layer

I create the VectorLayer on OpenLayers 7 from GeoJSON:

```
const geojson = "...";
const style = {...};
const vectorSource = new VectorSource({
  features: new GeoJSON().readFeatures(geojson, {
    featureProjection: "EPSG:3857",
    dataProjection: "EPSG:4326"
  })
});
const vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: style,
});
```

And after that, if I want to reproject these layer or source to other projrction (E.g. EPSG:4311), how can I do it?

If `geojson` variable is last, I can reload data from same data source, but once `geojson` variable is missing, I don't know how to get the result...

Comment: If you have a vector source on a map such as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/projection-and-scale.html you would need to run `vectorSource.forEachFeature((f) => { f.getGeometry().transform(currentProjection, newProjection); });` when changing the view projection if you did not want to reload the source.

Comment: Tahnk you! I'll try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created function like this and solved this problem:
(Same with the answer of [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/460985/how-to-filter-geojson-features-with-bbox-condition-in-openlayers))

```
const filterGeoJSON = (source, options) => {
  const extent = options.extent;
  const projectTo = options.projectTo;
  const retSource = new ol.source.Vector();
  source.forEachFeature((f) => {
    let retF = f.clone();
    if (projectTo) {
      retF.setGeometry(retF.getGeometry().transform("EPSG:4326", projectTo));
    }
    if (!extent || retF.getGeometry().intersectsExtent(extent)) {
      retSource.addFeature(retF);
    }
  });
  return retSource;
};

const geojson = (Some GeoJSON definition);
const projection = (Some projection definition);

const geojsonSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geojson, {
    featureProjection: "EPSG:4326",
    dataProjection: "EPSG:4326",
  }), 
});

const expectedSource = filterGeoJSON(geojsonSource, {
  extent: projection.getExtent(),
  projectTo: projection
});
```