# How to filter GeoJSON features with bbox condition in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, geojson, extents

I want to filter GeoJSON features with bbox condition in OpenLayers 7, so I coded like this:

```
  const geojson = (Some GeoJSON definition);
  const projection = (Some projection definition);


  const geojsonSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geojson, {
      featureProjection: projection,
      dataProjection: "EPSG:4326",
      filter: ol.format.filter.bbox("geometry", projection.getExtent(), projection.getCode())
    }),
  });
```

But no features were filtered with this code.
How can I filter them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating function like this:

```
const filterGeoJSON = (source, options) => {
  const extent = options.extent;
  const projectTo = options.projectTo;
  const retSource = new ol.source.Vector();
  source.forEachFeature((f) => {
    let retF = f.clone();
    if (projectTo) {
      retF.setGeometry(retF.getGeometry().transform("EPSG:4326", projectTo));
    }
    if (!extent || retF.getGeometry().intersectsExtent(extent)) {
      retSource.addFeature(retF);
    }
  });
  return retSource;
};

const geojson = (Some GeoJSON definition);
const projection = (Some projection definition);

const geojsonSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geojson, {
    featureProjection: "EPSG:4326",
    dataProjection: "EPSG:4326",
  }), 
});

const expectedSource = filterGeoJSON(geojsonSource, {
  extent: projection.getExtent(),
  projectTo: projection
});
```